# Table partitioning in MYSQL Master Slave

Tags: mysql, replication, partitioning, alter-table

I have to Partition a MYSQL table using Range partitioning. Table is 200M rows big and I have Master/Slave replication.

What I want to do is to stop replication on slave, partition the table on slave and start replication. My question for you guys is would this work despite the fact Master would have no partitioning on that table but slave would have roughly 50 partitions of that table?

Would replication still work ?

Comment: in principle it should work fine, I do exactly the same thing here.

Comment: So I basically just use start slave command after partitioning and replication will be all ok and that table would receive data from master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-features-differing-tables.html) does not list a problem, but...

Statement Based Replication should not have any problem since the Slave simply re-executes the DML statement without knowing or caring (up front) about whether the table is partitioned.

Some rare statements are very likely to break replication:

```
SELECT ... PARTITION pnnn -- 5.6.2
ALTER TABLE -- to change PARTITIONs
```

Please comment on [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77329) if you find more issues.